# Is it possible to run one RSpec test before the others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I use `factory_bot` with my tests and want to validate all factories before any of the tests will run. I wrote a test for such validation and want it to run first - is this feasible in RSpec?

Comment: Why do you want this test to run first? Just use `focus: true` until that test passes, then run your entire suite.

Comment: Because if factories test fails, almost all my suite will inevitably fail as well. I want to know that from the beginning and save those precious minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is feasible, see this post: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/testing-your-factories-first. The approach is to create a `factories_spec` and then add it as a pre-requisite to the `rake file`.

(1) Create a factories spec file:

```
 # spec/factories_spec.rb    
FactoryBot.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
  describe "The #{factory_name} factory" do
    it 'is valid' do
      expect(build(factory_name)).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

(2) To add a pre-requisite to your rake spec:

```
# Rakefile    
if defined?(RSpec)
  desc 'Run factory specs.'
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:factory_specs) do |t|
    t.pattern = './spec/factories_spec.rb'
  end
end

task spec: :factory_specs
```

(3) Run your test with

```
rake spec
```

Comment: Thank you. I've actually seen this post before, but figured I don't want to use `rake spec` instead of `rspec` just because of one test. Do you think there's a workaround here so I could keep using `rspec`?

Comment: I am not aware of any, sorry.